# I am failed to retrieve data using DB:table() in laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-6

I am failed to retrieve any date with this code

```
$data = DB::table('students')
          ->where([
            'students.school_id' => $school_id,
            'students.status' => true,
            'students.class'  => $request->class,
            'students.section'  => $request->section,
            'student_attendances.date' => "'$today'",
            'students.school_id' => 'student_attendances.school_id'
            ])
          ->leftJoin('student_attendances', 'students.rfid_number', '=', 'student_attendances.uid')
          ->get();
```

above code returning this query:

```
select * from `students` left join `student_attendances` on `students`.`rfid_number` = `student_attendances`.`uid` where (`students`.`school_id` = 1 and `students`.`status` = 1 and `students`.`class` = 1 and `students`.`section` = 1 and `student_attendances`.`date` = '2020-03-16' and `students`.`school_id` = student_attendances.school_id)
```

I have tried this query in mysql database and successfully getting data.
And also below code is working fine :

```
$sql_query_text = "select * from students left join student_attendances on students.rfid_number = student_attendances.uid where (students.school_id = student_attendances.school_id and students.status = 1 and students.class = '{$request->class}' and students.section = '{$request->section}' and date(student_attendances.created_at) = '$today')";

$data = DB::select($sql_query_text);
```

I could not understand what is the fault. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: check `"'$today'"`  it correctly passed or not...

Comment: could you tried like this  `'student_attendances.date' => $today,`

Comment: Yes Sir, it returns integer instead of a string like `student_attendances`.`date` = 2020-03-16

Comment: how did you echoed...

Comment: I passed 1 wrong column name, school_id as school_id1, then Laravel showed the query with error

Comment: and, just put the where condition one by one and find out where is the problem...

Comment: Thank You, the problem is with `'students.school_id' => 'student_attendances.school_id'`, but `select * from students left join student_attendances on students.rfid_number = student_attendances.uid where (students.school_id = student_attendances.school_id)` this query is working in mysql datebase query

Comment: Is it because I'm matching against 2 different tables in `->where([ 'students.school_id' => 'student_attendances.school_id'])` ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is

```
'students.school_id' => 'student_attendances.school_id'
```

Joint table condition can not be used in `->where()`  so I use

```
->leftJoin('student_attendances', function($join){
      $join->on('students.rfid_number', '=', 'student_attendances.uid');
      $join->on('students.school_id', '=', 'student_attendances.school_id');
    })
```

And this solved my purpose